# wget files by pattern only from specified directories recursively

Tags: wget

I need to download on an hourly basis (sometimes more frequently), files which are being written in segments of 24 hours. The files I am interested in are in specific subdirectories which I am trying to specify with `-I list` but this doesn't work for some reason.

If I don't specify directories the files I need download fine with the `-A acclist` option but I end up with lots of empty directories that are being created because they exist on the host.

my current line reads:

```
wget -np -nH --cut-dirs=X -c -N -r -l 0 \
     -I /dir1,/dir2,...,/some_dir -A acclist \
     http://hostname/X_sub_directories/
```

How do I download **only** the files I want and create **only** the directory hierarchy for those files?